# Get custom url field from database in phtm Magento 2

Tags: sql, url, magento, view, magento2

I have table with question and answer and i get all question.
But i need to get ONE my question like this faq/index/view/id/1 where id is id my question and answer.
my code

```
<?php
```

namespace Vendor\Name\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Display extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
private $collectionFactory;

```
/**
 * Display constructor.
 * @param Template\Context $context
 * @param \Vendor\Name\Model\ResourceModel\Faqmodel\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    Template\Context $context,
    \Vendor\Name\Model\ResourceModel\Faqmodel\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    array $data = []
) {

    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
}

public function sayHello()
{
    $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('status', 1);
    return $collection->getItems();
}
```

}
?>

```
<?php  foreach ($block->sayHello() as $fq):?>
    <a href="<?php echo $block->getUrl('faq/index/view', ['id'=> $fq->getId()]) ?>"><?php echo $fq->getQuestion()?></a> </br>
<?php endforeach?>
```

How to get in url faq/index/view/id/1 DB data with question and answer with id = 1.
and I will be able to get the question and answer depending on the url

Answer (score 0):

Create a frontend controller

```
Vendor/Module/Controller/Index/View.php
```

and get the id

```
$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
```

Use the id above to filter your collection